# New Relic alert policy for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, alerts

I am monitoring my Spring Boot application using the New Relic micrometer library. The metrics are showing up fine. Now, I want to create an alert policy for the application. Here, after categorising the policy, the next step is selecting an entity for which the options are empty. Thus, I am not able to move forward with creating the alerts.

Attaching an image for reference: [image: Empty entity]

What is the reason for this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

New Relic "Application" alerts are applied to the Application/Service entities (See your "Explorer" tab filtered to "Service"). In order to ensure that micrometer telemetry is associated with "Services" ensure that the SpringBoot instrumentation includes the `serviceName` of the application in the `newRelicRegistryConfig`.

```
public class NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public NewRelicRegistryConfig newRelicConfig() {
    return new NewRelicRegistryConfig() {

      (...)
    
      @Override
      public String serviceName() {
        return "My Service Name";
      }

    };
  }
```